# Column Ordering in Bootstrap3 not working as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was doing some experiments with column ordering in Bootstrap 3 and came across this problem.

How can I achieve the following order:

- XS: 123
- SM: 231
- MD: 312
- LG: 123

This is what I have: `LG` doesnt work and displays `<blank>13` instead of `123`

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-push-4 col-lg-pull-0">1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-4 col-md-push-4 col-lg-pull-0">2</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-4 col-md-pull-8 col-lg-pull-0">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention to the `push` and `pull` classes you're setting for each column, at the `lg` size you need to reset those that were set in smaller sizes. So for the first column you need to reset `push` not pull and for the second you need to reset both:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-push-4 col-lg-push-0">1</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-4 col-md-push-4 col-lg-pull-0 col-lg-push-0">2</div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-4 col-md-pull-8 col-lg-pull-0">3</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/5QEyU/7/show)**

**UPDATE**

To answer your question on why in this case it's not needed to reset the pull on the middle column at medium size:

Bootstrap uses the `left` and `right` CSS properties to push and pull the columns respectively and when you're at the medium size breakpoint both properties are set (since values from smaller sizes are propagated to the larger ones), when this happens, it's defined in the [CSS specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right) that the `left` property (push) has precedence and the `right` property is effectively ignored.

This means that if you were to have the classes in reverse order, first pushing and then pulling you WOULD need to reset the left property using `col-md-push-0`:

```
<div class="col-sm-pull-4 col-md-push-4">No Reset (Push has precedence)</div>
<div class="col-sm-push-4 col-md-pull-4 col-md-push-0">Reset is needed</div>
```

Comment: On that note, why don't I need to reset the `pull` class in `md`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there's a conflict in the default BS css, or atleast you get unexpected results, when you use multiple push / pull classes in the same div.

I have your HTML working when I add the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.col-sm-push-8, .col-md-push-4{
left:0;
}

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/S3apb/)
Hope this helps!